# Zero-ing Compass | Following Magnet Strip Robot

Tags: programming, library, mathematics

So my problem is purely programming, I understand the problem but can't figure out what to do, Is there a library? should I create my own code for Zero-ing my compass so I don't have value from earth field in my equasion?

I have a small robot that I want it to follow a refrigerator magnet strip that is incrustated in floor
The compass on its own works well but I want to be able to drive my robots by a positive or negative value that I would receive from a library/function I coded off values from library of compass

The actual problem is that earth magnetic field will offset my value

Lets say north is on the left and magenet is also on the left. I should receive for example -1000 Gauss
but then if I put the magnet to the right but keep the same oriantationg of the magnet I will receive -500 when I really wanted 500 for example.

Now id like to take a measurement of earth magnetic field first and from there subtract current value off the actual values i get.
But my understanding of vector is very limited.

Doing this for a compass that its oriantation don't change would be pretty simple but, in my case compass will be mounted on robot itself therefore orientation will change all the time

Im not looking for some code but more a general idea on how to do this, either by using a library or some maths idea on how to acheive that.

Comment: As you've noted, the fact that your platform rotates means that you can't directly do this.  First consider if the earth's field really makes enough difference when you are close to the strip.  If it does, you might need to add orientation tracking via wheel encoders and/or a gyroscope (tricky but getting surprisingly good in drones). Or perhaps you should look at using two sensors displaced left and right, or one near the ground and one raised in the air to detect the earth reference field with less influence from the strip.

Comment: Thanks @Chirs i could put one in the midle and the substract from this.  But i really feel like its posible to get a reading with nothing except earth mag field and use it as a calibration to substract and get only the actual magets around the sensor on each axis on all axis.  I just dont know where to start for this

Comment: It might be easier to use hall effect sensors instead of a compass. Use them like optical sensors for a normal line following robot.

Comment: @Majenko Yep I would do that, but i want to utilize the north and south pole of the magenet, so i can count where the robot is at in its trajectory.

Comment: @NicolasRacine analog hall sensors detect the polarity of the field not just the strength

Comment: i don't know if this would work, but you could try to orient the compass along one of the other axes. ... or use a separate compass along each axis

Comment: @jsotola What do you mean?  Can you elaborate ?

Comment: i used the compass app on my phone to detect the magnetic seal on my fridge .... i got a different response when i turned the phone sideways ... i was talking about the xyz axes in 3d space in my comment